# heavy prime number in java

Tags: java

1. A prime heavy number is defined to be one that is the sum of more than one pair of prime numbers. Recall that a prime number is a number greater than 1 whose only divisors are 1 and itself.
   For example, 16 is prime heavy because 16=3+13 and 5+11 (note that 3, 5, 11, and 13 are all prime). 24 is prime heavy because 24 = 5+19, 7+17 and 11+13. However, 8 is not prime heavy because 8 = 3+5 but no other pair of primes sums to 8.
   Write a function named isPrimeHeavy that returns 1 if its argument is prime heavy, otherwise it returns 0.
   The function signature is
   int isPrimeHeavy (int n) 
   You may assume that a function named isPrime already exists that returns 1 if its argument is a prime. You can call this function but do not have to write it.

I did this but it cant return a heavy prime..just returns a prime number...

```
public class Prime {

    public static boolean isPrimeHeavy(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isPrimeHeavy(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i = i + 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class PrimeTest {

    public PrimeTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsPrime() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        Prime prime = new Prime();
        TreeMap<Long, String> methodMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();


        for (Method method : Prime.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int primeCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                if ((Boolean) method.invoke(prime, i)) {
                    primeCount++;
                }
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Assert.assertEquals(method.getName() + " failed ", 78498, primeCount);
            methodMap.put(endTime - startTime, method.getName());
        }


        for (Entry<Long, String> entry : methodMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey() + " Milli seconds ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must show code and tag it as homework. Stackoverflow will not do not your homework for you.

Comment: its not a homework,its an interview question and i need an answer ASAP...an defeated i dont even have a code for it

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: If you're in the middle of an actual interview and you're asking StackOverflow to help you answer your questions...you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: You are writing tests for prime numbers, not a test for your "prime heavy" numbers.  You definition needs to be more precise, actually.  8 is 5 + 3 and also 7 + 1, so why is it not "prime heavy"?  Can you not use 1?

Comment: @davidfmatheson - 1 is not a prime number.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a single loop to try all the possible first values and you can calculate the second, when you find there is more than one pair, return 1, otherwise return 0.

I have given you this much as a hint because its maths really rather than programming. You will find problems like this at Project Euler. IMHO You shouldn't be expected to know how to solve the maths problem unless you are employed for a maths role, but you should be able to write the code if you are a professional developer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((argument % 2 == 0 && argument > 12) || argument == 10) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Prime {

    public static boolean isPrimeHeavy(int n) {
        if (n % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = n-3; i >= (n/2); i -= 2) {
            if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(n - i)) {
                found++;
                if (found == 2)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This never returns zero or one.

Comment: You can treat `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`. Logically `isPrimeHeavy` returns `true` if `n` is indeed prime heavy or `false` if `n` is not prime heavy.